# Automatically SMS seding on php through api

Tags: php

im working on a project that sending sms for client is required when he reaches atarget point  i write the code but it returns message "moved permanennty and this message isn't wanted.

code

```
$data="username=".$username."&password=".$password."&numbers=".$to."&sender=".$sender."&message=".$msg1;
$ch=curl_init("http://hisms.ws/api.php?send_sms&".$data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
```

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);$result=curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);

result 
is The document has moved here.

Comment: Maybe try another SMS provider?

Comment: or provider didn't accept the post header, try to set header before POST.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the request with GET method, not POST. For this you need to set 0 (or `false`) instead of 1 in the third parameter:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
```

Or you can just remove this line of code.